# Flyway - Is there an easier way to use this?

Tags: phpstorm, flyway

Flyway doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me, in that it seems like a lot of work to maintain.

When I'm working, it's a pain to have to create a sql file in the migration folder and then migrate it to update the database. Not being able to make changes directly in the DB console, significantly affects my work. Is there something I'm missing, such as an easier way to keep track of changes to my DB? Also, I have to make a new migration file each time I want to update the database. I can't just update an already migrated sql file.

The ideal way, would be for me to make changes in the DB (via the console) and at the end of the day, do some type of dump that tracked all my changes into a single sql file. Is there a way to do this?

I'm using PhpStorm as my Ide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flyway is best used to setup a CI toolchain to migrate changes to your test/QA/Prod. Yes, in your dev instance its best to create your tables through a cli / UI and once you are ready to migrate your changes to integration, you may generate your sql scripts to use with your build.